# Unlimited nested reference in include

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 classes Resources and ResourceTypes

```c#
public class Resource {
  public int ID;
  public string name;
  public int ResourceTypeID;
}

public class ResourceType {
  public int ID;
  public ICollection<Resource> Resources;
}
```

Resource has 1 to 1 relation with ResourceType but resource type has 1 to many relationship with Resource.

when I use `_context.Resource.Include(r => r.ResourceType).ToList()`, the result that I get has

Resource (containing ResourceType Object containing Multiple Resource Objects and recursively)

Please advice how to avoid this.

Comment: I believe in `ResourceType` you would store a `List<int>` of `Resource Ids` which would hold foreign keys to the `Resource Objects`. It may be beneficial to post your table schemas as well

Comment: I just fixed it now.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct

Comment: With `resource ids` in `resourcetype` you can `join` the two tables together, using the `foreign keys` held in `resourcetype` to the `primary key` `ID` in `resource`. I think you can do away with the `ResourceTypeId` in the class `Resource` altogether.

Comment: That is how it is. When we check the query, the result is fine and as expected. However. the list that gets created is recursive and it goes on and on:. see the example of the result

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this? You can't. If a `Resource` has a `ResourceType` (the property is not in your model by the way) you *want* the `ResourceType` to contain the `Resource` in its `Resources` collection. If you have problems in Json serialization you'll find many questions (and answers) on that topic here.